# NodeJS/MongoDB function returning array with wrong data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so I have a collection where I will have a lot of documents, but for now lets suppose it has about 100. (It had less than that when I was testing).

So, I need to get all the documents of the collection, put in a array, sort that and then send it to the websocket for the frontend. But the array is going with wrong data.

This is my code:

```
const emitSales = async (socket) => {

  let salesArray = [];
  const saleExists = (contract) => {
    return salesArray.some(element => element.contract === contract);
  }
  const addSale = (contract) => {
    const element = salesArray.find(e => e.contract === contract);
    element.sales = element.sales+1;
  }

  const sales = await fiveMinSchema.find({}).lean();
  if(sales) {
    for await (x of sales) {
      if(saleExists(x.contract)) {
        addSale(x.contract);
        continue;
      }
      const collection = await Collection.findOne({
        contract: x.contract
      });

      let newsale = {
        contract: x.contract,
        title: collection.title,
        description: collection.description,
        image: collection.image,
        sales: 1,
      }
      salesArray.push(newsale);
    }

    socket.emit("5min", salesArray.sort((a,b) => {
      return b.sales-a.sales;
    }).slice(0,10));
  }

}
```

So, when I execute this function only once, for example, the array returns the correct values. But if I execute the function like 2 times in a row (like very fast), it starts returning the array with wrong data. (like mixing the data).

And as I using websocket, this function will execute like every 2 seconds (for example). How can I fix this problem? Like it seems to be executing more than one time simultaneously and mixing the data, idk..

Comment: Why u dont use mongodb sort method?

Comment: How would I sort that using the mongodb method? As I have to get the collection out of the sales